# UIScrollView contents not allowing user interaction

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled like the following:

```
container = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:kScrollViewFrame];
[container setDelegate:self];
[container setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[container setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[container setClipsToBounds:YES];
[container setPagingEnabled:YES];
[container setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast];
[container setBounces:NO];
[container setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[container setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
[container setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```

To the UIScrollView, I add several UIWebViews, and set their interaction enabled to yes like so.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.frame = frame;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

which breaks paging and all touches on the UIScrollView. If I set user interaction enabled to NO, page works, but I can't highlight text in the UIWebView. I tried subclassing UIScrollView like the following, but the same circumstances occur. Any idea?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSLog(@"init");
    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");

    [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");

    [[self nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
    [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve, do you need the scroll view scrolling, web view scrolling, paging, selecting? Please be more specific.

Comment: I need the scroll view to page and the user to be able to select text on the webvies (which are subviews of the scrollview) Webview does not need to scroll, just be able to have its text selected.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your requirements, it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Beware: the docs tell you not to put UIWebViews inside UIScrollViews in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disabling user interaction on the container effectively disables it on the subviews as well. You should enable it, causing the touch event to propagate down the view hierarchy;

```
[container setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

If you want to disable scrolling on the UIWebView just get inside its `UIScrollView`

```
yourWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

I've tested this on my device and I can both "page through" the UIScrollView and select text on UIWebView.

EDIT:

I got this working! You have to allow touch canceling as well:

```
[container setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
```

Comment: I have tried this and it breaks user interaction on the webviews which are children of the scrollview.

Comment: I tried this and I can no longer scroll, even tho content size of uiscrollview is 10,000px and the frame is set to the screens width/height (768 x 1024) Edit: Actually, it works if I hold down for several seconds and try to swipe. It's very difficult to page. Are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: Used a swipe recognizer and animated the paging myself.